# VSCode Doesn't Show Disassembly Option

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a VSCode extension and would like to give the use the ability to disassemble their program.

In the initialize request I'm setting `supportsDisassembleRequest` to true, however the option doesn't appear while debugging.

Are there other pre-requisites that need to be enabled to allow this functionality?

This is what I return for a `InitializeRequest`:

```json
{
    "body": {
        "additionalModuleColumns": [
        ],
        "completionTriggerCharacters": [
        ],
        "exceptionBreakpointFilters": [
        ],
        "supportedChecksumAlgorithms": [
        ],
        "supportsDisassembleRequest": true,
        "supportsReadMemoryRequest": true,
        "supportsWriteMemoryRequest": true
    },
    "command": "initialize",
    "request_seq": 1,
    "seq": 1,
    "success": true,
    "type": "response"
}
```

The ability to read\write memory *does* work!

Edit: When generating the call stack, you need to set `InstructionPointerReference` on the StackFrame so you can rt-click the stack to disassemble. But still not rt click the code window itself like shows in the release notes.

Comment: where do you write this JSON

Comment: Its the reply from the debug adapter to VSCode for the Initilise request. eg https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Types_Capabilities